# Simpler way to write this code?

Tags: c#, simplify

This is for my button named Edit, when you have an entry into the shopping basket and click on the entry and click Edit it opens up a new window which allows you to edit the entries, product name, quantity or price. This is what I have and it compiles and runs fine but is there an easier way to write it?

```
private void btn_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lst_Results.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Want to edit the value of the Item
        Edit editbutton = new Edit();

        editbutton.NameOfItem =
        basket.Items[lst_Results.SelectedIndex].ItemName;
        editbutton.Quantity = basket.Items[lst_Results.SelectedIndex].Quantity;
        editbutton.ReplacementValue =
        basket.Items[lst_Results.SelectedIndex].Price;


        if (editbutton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            basket.UpdateReplacementValue(basket.Items[lst_Results.SelectedIndex].ItemName, editbutton.Quantity, editbutton.ReplacementValue);
            RenderLibrary();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the problem with this code?

Comment: This should probably have been posted in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, you can write out the repeating array access.

```
// Want to edit the value of the Item
Edit editbutton = new Edit();

var item = basket.Items[lst_Results.SelectedIndex];

editbutton.NameOfItem = item.ItemName;
editbutton.Quantity = item.Quantity;
editbutton.ReplacementValue = item.Price;

if (editbutton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    basket.UpdateReplacementValue(item.ItemName, editbutton.Quantity, editbutton.ReplacementValue);
    RenderLibrary();
}
```

Also, you might want to just pass the object as parameter to the control, and edit it there using data binding.

Comment: thank you, this makes it look much easier to read :)

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing that? ^^